# Are there predictable, yet secure hashes?

Tags: hash, public-key

*My original problem:* I want Alice to be able to promise that at some point in the future she will upload a statement to an address in a hash-table, which is computable/predictable from everyone without knowing her secret key (to be able to look at that address, if the statement is already there). However, the statement should not be predictable for everyone.

*One solution path*:
Alice has a secret key $S$ and the corresponding public key $P$ (solutions for any (secure) key generation algorithms are appreciated). Is there any combination of (any) functions $f_1, f_2$ and (any) hashing algorithms $h_1, h_2$, s.t. the following holds?

$h_1(f_1(P)) = h_2(f_2(S, P))$

I.e. an algorithm that gives a predictable hash for data generated by the secret key. A hash that can be generated from the public key only, which will be the same for a string generated from the secret (and possibly the public) key.

*Important note:* $f_1$ may not be aware of $S$, of course, and $f_2$ may not ignore $S$. Otherwise there are of course trivial solutions...

**My question**: Can my proposed solution be workable or is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: Do you need $h_1 \not\equiv h_2$? Because that goes against the idea of a secure hash function. You are therefore left with $h_1 \equiv h_2$ and therefore $f_1(P) \equiv f_2(S, P)$ (I hope I have the math notation correct).

Comment: What about $h_1$=$f_1$=identity, $h_2$=RSA public key operation, $f_2$=RSA private key operation?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes $h1=h2$ or $h1 \not= h2$, that's not important. But presumably different hashing functions will not generate the same hash.

Comment: @CodesInChaos can you elaborate a bit, I don't really understand I think...

Comment: @CodesInChaos, only if you allow hash functions to have variable length output.

Comment: @hildensia, thanks. A few more questions. I'm assuming Alice knows what the statement is at the time she makes the promise. When the finally makes the statement, anyone who has the original promise should be able to verify that the statement hasn't changed. Are there any bit limitations on the size of the promise? Why are hash-tables necessary?

Comment: I made some edits to make the question a little more broad. If you don't like the changes, feel free to roll back.

Comment: I really don't understand your original problem.  If you want the hash address to be public, but not the statement that Alice will upload, why don't you have Alice publish the hash address (alternatively, make it a function of her public key)?  Obviously, from that, no one can recover the statement until Alice publishes it.  What do you need that this simple solution does not supply?

Comment: You skipped a step: before looking into whether a security goal is achievable, you must clearly (i.e., formally) define that goal, which you haven't done.

Comment: @hildensia  But presumably different hashing functions will not generate the same hash all the time: you would need a hash function that produces the same hash for each $S$ and $P$ / output of $f_1$ and $f_2$. And unless the hash functions are equivalent I would not hold my breath trying to find a collision for $h_1$ and $h_2$ in the first place.

Comment: In the original problem, from what data is the address _"computable/predictable"_ by anyone? Is that that same as $P$ in the proposed solution? In that purposed solution, is $S$ Alice's statement, Alice's secret key, or both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds to me like you want to is produce a hash that proves *integrity*, and can be *authenticated* with some key pair.

In that case, I would release a *HMAC* using a *RSA public key* and your statement along with the *RSA signature* of the aforementioned *HMAC*.

That way someone could verify the *integrity* and *authenticity* of your statement while only knowing your *RSA public key* and the signed *HMAC*.